# Are POI colors limited to IndexedColors?

Tags: java, excel, colors, apache-poi

I'm trying to set Excel cell colors using Apache POI in Java. I played around in Excel itself and chose the colors I wanted - but I can't figure out how to use those colors with POI. I'm using the `font.setColor` method, which takes a short that's the index of a color... Which seems to indicate that I'm limited to the constants in `IndexedColors`. Is there any way to set a cell to a hex color value? Or can I only use the predefined constants?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`HSSFPalette`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFPalette.html) class to query the defined colors and define your own colors as well (using [`setColorAtIndex()`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFPalette.html#setColorAtIndex(short,%20byte,%20byte,%20byte))).

Comment: Is there any way to do this without replacing the default colors?

Answer (score -1):

I'm working with HWPF, not HSSF and I'm too lazy to go looking, but do the cell/character format classes you're working with have an attribute named "ico24" or something similar? In HWPF, that's the `int` representation of a 24 bit (A)RGB color spec which can be used to specify any color you like.